# AccessToken , post to user wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I first check if user liked the page with this code:

```
 IFacebookApplication current = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("FaceBookApp")
                          as IFacebookApplication;

  FacebookSignedRequest decodedRequest = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(current,Request["signed_request"]);
            var q = ((JsonObject)decodedRequest.Data)["page"];
```

Then deserialize it etc...  and turn it into a strong typed object.

But how do I go from there to asking permission to access date of birth, name etc and permission to post to wall? Tried some things but none resulted in the dialog i'm used to seeing apps. Can't seem to figure it out.. Just wish there was some clear documentation <.>!

Answer (score 0):

Start by playing around with the Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.  This will teach you a lot about what the API can do.  Once you can do things there, doing it in the C# SDK is trivial.

Comment: Not really what I meant, probably should of just done it in php, api is horribly documented... or write my own

Comment: Did you get a chance to experiment with the Graph API Explorer tool?